# React: how to check and uncheck a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote this React component:

```
import React from 'react';
    
export default class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Set initial state
        this.state = {
            data: props.data
        }
    }

    changeStatus() {
        // This throws: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
        console.log(this.state);
        console.log('status changed');
    }

    render() {
        let status = this.state.data.opened ? 'opened' : 'closed';
        return (
            <li className={"todo " + status} data-endpoint={this.state.data['@id']}>
                <div className="status">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={!this.state.data.opened} onChange={this.changeStatus}/>
                </div>
                <a href={window.Routing.generate('todo_list_todo_show', {account: this.props.todoList.account.id, list: this.props.todoList.id, todo: this.state.data.id}, true)}>{this.state.data.name}</a>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

I want that the checkbox is checked and unchecked depending on the call to the server to update the row in the database.

Unfortunately the `console.log()` throws an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
>
> at changeStatus (Todo.jsx:20)

How can I access the `state` in the method that handles the change of the status?

Comment: Try `onChange={this.changeStatus.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `changeStatus` method in your constructor -

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Set initial state
        this.state = {
            data: props.data
        }
        this.changeStatus = this.changeStatus.bind(this);

    }
```

You can read why binding is required [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Comment: This should be a comment. I have seen so many similar post regarding this. We should look for such post and close this post instead of answering

Comment: @Rajesh excuse me for the repetition :(

Comment: @Aerendir let try to keep the discipline up from now on. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6, you can avoid typing the bind by using an arrow function.

This way `this` is bind automatically to the function.

```
changeStatus = () => {
        // This throws: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
        console.log(this.state);
        console.log('status changed');
    }
```

> Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so `this` actually refers
>   to the originating context.